# Why Qt Creator doesn't see QCoreApplication

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I've just installed Qt Creator and created console project. And when i want to run my project i have error: unknown type name 'QCoreApplication'. But i didn't write any code yet. Where is a problem, why qt doesn't see it?
My code is:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    return a.exec();
}
```

My .pro file is:

```
CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Comment: Did you try adding `QT += core` to your .pro file?

Answer (score 1):

@ADV Looks like your forgot include for [`QCoreApplication`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html), so it should be the first line of your `main.cpp` file:

```cpp
#include <QCoreApplication>
```

**UPD:**
Are you sure that you've choose valid Kit on Kit Selection phase:

[image: Kit Selection]

To check Kits you have go to Tools->Options->Kits and check if your kits are valid and contains no exclamation marks.

To change kit used for current projects open "Projects" tab:
[image: Projects tab]

and select different kit.

Comment: I have this line, it was there after project creation. Thank you, i edited question